# How do I serialize circular references?

Tags: c#, serialization

How do I serialise objects referencing each other?

```
public class Item {}

public class Player
{
    Item weapon;
}
```

Those instances live on their own somewhere: I have in some class a `List<Item> gameobjects` and in another class a tile class with a `List<Item> tileobjects`.

Comment: Most serialisation libraries can cope with this if you serialise everything into a single file

Comment: Well i was using System.Xml.Serialization and i intended to develop  my own if i would be able to solve this empass...

Comment: Solving that particular problem involves maintaining a dictionary of objects that have already been serialized. So if object A has already been serialized and you run across another reference to it, you output a reference. This assumes, of course, that your deserialization code understands how to handle the references. Honestly, though, unless you're doing something profoundly strange, you're better off using the built-in serialization. There are several options: XML Serialization, DataContractSerializer, Binary serialization, etc. Look into options before trying to do this yourself.

Comment: i wanted to do my own cause i dont think any of these work...
As for the dictionary you mean like using as keys each object in my program and search through each of them?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved a similar problem. Your serializer class should then keep track of those objects you have already serialized. For example, by adding its ID in a list of already parsed objects. If it is the first time, you should continue serializing the object, otherwise you can just write the ID.

When deserializing, recover this ID and check in your serializer class whether that object has already been deserialized. If so, recover the actual object and reconstruct the reference. Otherwise, deserialize the object and add its ID to another list of already deserialized objects.

For example, you might have a class like the following:

```
public class GraphSerializer 
{
    Dictionary<string, Node> parsedNodes;

    public void MarkNodeAsParsed(Node node)
    {
        parsedNodes.Add(node.Id, node);
    }

    public bool IsNodeParsed(string id)
    {
        return parsedNodes.ContainsKey(id);
    }

    public Node GetNode(string id)
    {
        return parsedNodes[id];
    }

    [...]
}
```

Now when serializing you would do something like this, in pseudocode:

```
public void Serialize(GraphSerializer serializer, ...)
{
    serializer.Write(node.Id);

    bool isNewNode = !serializer.IsNodeParsed(node.Id);
    if (isNewNode) 
    {
        // Write rest of data
        serializer.Write(node);
        serializer.MarkNodeAsParsed(node);
    }

    // Since this node has already been serialized, we don't need  
    // to serialize any other value as we have already written the node Id
}
```

Then, when deserializing:

```
public void Deserialize(GraphSerializer serializer, ...)
{
    string id = serializer.ReadString();
    Node node;

    bool isNewNode = !serializer.IsNodeParsed(node.Id);
    if (isNewNode) 
    {
        // Read rest of data
        node = serializer.Read();
        serializer.MarkNodeAsParsed(node);
    }
    else
    {
        // Node has already been deserialized, so we can just recover it
        node = serializer.GetNode(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems quite complicated, do you have come portion of code you could share?

Comment: yes but then i would have to make a own serialization that when serializing a Node, check in its proerties etc if some of them is in the node list, or not?

Comment: I guess that depends on your particular scenario. For example, assume there are two classes, `Node` and `ChildNode`. If `ChildNode` is always contained by `Node` instances, when you proceed to serialize all `Nodes` you will encounter all `ChildNode` instances needed. So there is no need to serialize a list of `ChildNode` instances.

When you deserialize the `Nodes`, you can populate a list of `ChildNode` instances by iterating through the vaious `Node` objects. Is this what you meant?

Comment: yeah but in my scenario is all generic,its like having a list ot all bird, all trees and all apples, some bird will live in some tree but not all, some tree will have some apple but not all, some all will be bitten by some bird but not all, so basically i have just some list ofthings, with few references to various entities, but its never pyramidal

Comment: Well you are going to traverse those list anyways. All objects that could also appear somewhere else will need to be checked using this fashion. 

Otherwise, if you use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx) you can simply set `IsReference` to true and it will take care of circular references for you.